# Drawing lines showing connections between geocoordiante points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, latitude-longitude, connection, points-to-line

I have an ArcMap document with 100 locations plotted using their latitude and longitude values. I want to show connections between the 100 points in the graph. Essentially 100*100 = 10,000 lines. Is there a way to construct a graph showing these connections using ArcMap?

Comment: [Points To Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/points-to-line.htm) will work for display purposes, but it will return one huge polyline unless you have an Advanced license to use [Split Line At Vertices](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/split-line-at-vertices.htm) to chop it up into 10,000 lines.

Answer (score 1):

One solution (and a great chance to implement `itertools`) would be:

```
import arcpy, os, itertools

infc = r"C:\MyFolder\MyGDB\MyInputFeatureClass" # Replace with the path to your input feature class
outfc = r"C:\MyFolder\MyGDB\MyOutputFeatureClass" # Replace with the path to your output feature class
spatialref = arcpy.Describe(infc).spatialReference

if not arcpy.Exists(outfc):
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.dirname(outfc), os.path.basename(outfc), "POLYLINE", "", "", "", spatialref)

points = [arcpy.Point(row[0][0], row[0][1]) for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, "SHAPE@XY")]

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outfc, "SHAPE@") as cursor:
    for combination in itertools.combinations(points, 2):
        line = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array(combination))
        cursor.insertRow((line,))
```

Make sure the path you copy-and-paste from ArcCatalog/Windows explorer is in a raw string `r""`. And the input has a coordinate system defined, or define one using [Define Projection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/define-projection.htm).

Comment: Points to Line will not work as I tested it, because that was the first thing that came to my mind as well. It will connect all the points, but it will not connect every point with every *other* point. Well, actually it was the second thing I thought of, with OD Cost Matrix of Network Analyst being the first, but since there's no network to use... @Ross it may also be worth adding to your question whether straight-line or geodesic lines are desired.

Comment: @John I am getting a runtime error on line 5 spatialref = arcpy.Describe(infc).spatialReference . I am not sure why ?

Comment: Don't expect 100×100 lines. It's n×(n-1) combinations for n-long set

Comment: Hi Ross, is your _infc_ an existing point feature class with a coordinate system defined? Or is the path correct? You'll need to use a _raw string_ to define the path, such as `r"C:\Users\Ross\Desktop\My Docs\Data\SampleGDB.gdb\PointFC"`.

Comment: You're right @ChrisW. I went back and verified and it doesn't create a matrix, just a straight path through each point 1-100. Edited and remove from answer. Thanks for the check.

Comment: Hi John, I corrected the error in line 5. But I get another error on line 8 arcpy.CreateFeatureClass.... It says Attribute error : 87931. I haven't worked with python before and your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Go ahead @Ross and send me an email and we can get it straightened out: _jtran20@masonlive.gmu.edu_. Include a screenshot of the _entire_ error message and your code.